# Post edit screen: How to check if meta_box is registered?

Tags: metabox

I got some custom post types where i deregistered the "title" meta box. Now i always get "Auto Draft" as title. To avoid this i'd like to add the name of a taxonomy as the title. But how would i check if the meta box "title" exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the metabox global directly?

`$wp_meta_boxes['YOURTYPE']` should hold data on metaboxes for a given type.

Had a quick look in `wp-admin/includes/template.php` but i can't see any convenience functions for extracting metabox information from the array so you'll probably need to create your own code to loop over or extract the necessary info from it.

Of course make sure you run your code after the `add_meta_boxes` actions(else they'll likely not exist at the point you run your code).

Comment: It's exactly (or better said, should exactly be - no success so far): `$wp_meta_boxes['bills']['high']['post_title']`

Comment: That'll be because the title is not a metabox, maybe run your conditional logic in the same way core does decides whether to show that field, ie. `if ( post_type_supports( 'bills', 'title') ) { ` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this code which works.

Reference: https://gist.github.com/trinitybranding/72066ca34584535dccbe3290dee02791

I renamed the original function name.

```
function __hasMetabox( $meta_box_id, $post_type = false ){
  global $wp_meta_boxes, $grist_meta_box_found;
    $grist_meta_box_found = false; // assume not found by default
    // if meta boxes are not yet set up, let's issue an error
    if( empty( $wp_meta_boxes ) or ! is_array( $wp_meta_boxes ) )
        return new WP_Error( 'missing-meta-boxes', 'global $wp_meta_boxes is not the expected array' );
    // should we only look at meta boxes for a specific post type?
    if ( $post_type )
        $meta_boxes = $wp_meta_boxes[ $post_type ];
    else
        $meta_boxes = $wp_meta_boxes;
    // step through each meta box registration and check if the supplied id exists
    array_walk_recursive( $meta_boxes, function( $value, $key, $meta ){
        global $grist_meta_box_found;
        if ( $key === 'id' and strtolower( $value ) === strtolower( $meta )  )
            $grist_meta_box_found = true;
    }, $meta_box_id );
    $return = $grist_meta_box_found; // temp store the return value
    unset( $grist_meta_box_found );  // remove var from from global space
    return $return;
}
```

Then just run something like...

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() {
  global $wp_meta_boxes, $post;
  if (__hasMetabox('submitdiv', $post->post_type))
  $wp_meta_boxes[$post->post_type]['side']['core']['submitdiv']['title'] = 'Amazing!!!';
});
```

Output Example:

[image]